# Bind empty string to Guid.Empty or avoid model state error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, validation, model-binding

When I post a form with an empty string "" for a `Guid` field I get the error "The MyGuid field is required." although I haven't set the "Required" attribute.

```
//NOT Required   
public Guid MyGuid { get; set; }
```

after model binding the Guid is `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` (because it's the default value) and that's correct. But the ModelState has the mentioned error.

How can I avoid this error?

*Additional Info*:

`[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]` does not help

I don't want to make the Guid nullable (`Guid?`) because this would lead to a lot additional code (checking if it has a value, mapping and so on)

**Update:**

OK, I figured out that a change to `Guid?` in my view models doesn't result in that many changes than I expected (some calls to `MyGuid.GetValueOrDefault()` or some checks for `MyGuid.HasValue` and calls to `MyGuid.Value`).

However, the reason that a model error is added if no valid Guid is provided with the post request, is that the `DefaultModelBinder` tries to bind `null` to `Guid`. The solution would be to override the `DefaultModelBinder`. And no errors will be added to the model state

```
public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void SetProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) && value == null)
        {
            value = Guid.Empty;
        }
        base.SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Is there code that checks whether the Guid is `DefaultValue`?  It makes more sense to check for null/value than to check `DefaultValue`.  And storing `DefaultValue` instead of a null is just confusing - it's the equivalent of storing "empty string" instead of "".

Comment: Yes I have services and DAOs that are checking for Guid.Empty. The Guids I'm using here are all for retrieving data or setting references. I never store the default value of Guid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the type of the field is `Guid` (which is a value type), then it must contain a value (even if it’s all zeros). The correct solution to have a non-required GUID is to use `Guid?` (Nullable Guid).

Your reasons for not wanting to use Nullable don’t make sense; no matter which way you are going to encode “emptiness”, your code will have to check for it. I’d argue that Nullable actually makes this easier, generally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My code already handles the default Guid correctly (if it has to handle it at all). Changing it to an other type requires a lot of changes. And I have more than one non-required Guid in various ViewModels. Isn't There a way to tell the Model-binder to ignore errors when trying to bind "" to Guid?

Comment: @Fabiano: If your code handles the all-zeros GUID as a special “null” value, while admittedly this might work by and large, I would consider it rather hacky and a code smell. Future maintainers of your code have no way of telling from the type of the property that it might contain this magic value with a special meaning. If, on the other hand, you use `Guid?`, then it is immediately obvious that it could be `null`, and what that means. Therefore, I would argue that the changes necessary to your code to accommodate the Nullable type would be well worth it.

Comment: Ok, I made some test with changing the Guids to Guid?  It seems to work with some changes in the code to viewModel.MyGuid.GetValueOrDefault()

Comment: Using Guid? means you now have two empty values: null and Guid.Empty. This means all code should check for both. That makes using Guid better than Guid? because it makes a lot of code easier: if (myGuid != Guid.Empty) is better than if (myGuid != null && myGuid != Guid.Empty)

Answer (score 1):

in the sense of my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31268941/4985705 on  [ASP.NET MVC: types cast in model binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26673881/asp-net-mvc-types-cast-in-model-binding)
the following will return the Guid.Empty values or the Guid parameter, if it is desired.

```
public class NullableGuidBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Guid?))
        {
            var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

            string input = valueResult.AttemptedValue;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) || input == "0")
            {
                // return null, even if input = 0
                // however, that is dropdowns' "guid.empty")
                // base.BindModel(...) would fail converting string to guid, 
                // Guid.Parse and Guid.TryParse would fail since they expect 000-... format

                // add the property to modelstate dictionary
                var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
                bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
                return Guid.Empty;
            }
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

binding as follows in your controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SelectAction(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(NullableGuidBinder))] Guid? id)
    {
        // your stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application start event set: DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;

Keeping in mind this will make all value types not required unless explicitly set so.

I agree with Fabiano though. Guid is a bit of a freak with it's Guid.Empty.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't help